# Generation 1 trading?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

So I'm trying to trade Pokemon between two generation 1 games (Red and Yellow), but I can't quite seem to figure out how. I can find no explanations or guides on the internet anywhere.

So I hook my GBA SP and GBA with together with the connector cable, and then in both games go up to the lady in the Poke Centers and talk to her. All she says is "this area is for two friends hooked together by a Gameboy link cable" and that's it. So how do I active the trading process? What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pokemon Generation 1 (Red/Blue/Yellow) and Generation 2 (Gold/Silver/Crystal) games were designed for the original GameBoy and GameBoy Color systems.

The hardware of the GBA systems was a significant enough change that older games not developed in the brief overlap period like The Legend of Zelda: Oracle of Seasons/Ages are unable to use the newer link cables.

I have seen two possible solutions to this get some games to communicate over a link between two GBA systems:

1. Use an older-style [GBC link cable](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/gameboyadvance/hook_universallink.jsp)
2. Use two GBA link cables and link them into each-other. So that P1's link cable is connected to the box in the middle of P2's cable, and P2's cable is connected to the box in the middle of P1's cable. Forming something like `---<===>---`

   - I cannot personally vouch for this method, but it is one that turned up a few times in my research.

Comment: GBC link cables apparently do not work on GBA's because there is no where to plug them in.

Comment: GBC/GBP link cables do work on GBAs. The plug is a slightly different shape but the socket on the GBA accomodates both. DMG link cables on the other hand use a much larger connector.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right, GBA cables work differently from GBC cables. Since the games were originally made for the GBC, you'd need a GBC cable to trade between the two games.

Comment: I ordered a GBC link cable and it came, but it turns out the GBC link cables don't fit into GBA's. So waste of money there :/